# MYSQL query, taking messages

Tags: mysql

I need in help with query.
I have a messages table
[image]

And I have a page, where user can see with whom he have chated.
http://image.prntscr.com/image/97e49a49ed1d455da641d10166f8b706.png

How can I get all that users[ids] and the last texts with them, if we have ID of logged in user?

Comment: is your id column set to auto increment ?

Comment: Please put the data in the question, do not use images.

Comment: yes, ID is auto increment

Comment: With this query, I could take all the User ids, who chated with our user

`SELECT DISTINCT m_to FROM messages WHERE m_to != 24 
UNION SELECT DISTINCT m_from FROM messages WHERE m_from != 24`
where 24 is our users(in session) id

Comment: Please help?...